# Exporting attribute table to text file(.txt) in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export, text

I'm having trouble exporting **directly** an ArcGIS attribute table to a text file (.txt) while I'm working in ModelBuilder. I tried the followings and none of them worked:

- *Copy Rows* tool: I tried to add the (.txt) extension to the output table but it still gave a (.dbf) table.
- *Export Feature Attribute to ASCII*: It adds the coordinates (X, Y) which are not needed. Also, the order of the attributes is not the same as the one in the table.
- *Export table to Excel*: I know that it could work if I export my Excel file to a text file from the Excel panel but I'd prefer having this process completely automatic!

EDIT: LOOK AT THE COMMENTS AT THE BOTTOM

Comment: perhaps show the model steps as an image to provide some more information

Answer (score 6):

A way of converting an attribute table to a comma separated text file is to run the [Table to Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-geodatabase.htm) tool. The location would be a folder such as `c:\temp\mydata` and the output table would be `test.txt`. If you set the field mappings then you can choose which fields get exported.

But you may get yourself into trouble, what happens if a text value contains a comma? Personally I would keep the attribute table in a structured format such as a DBase format as that enforces data integrity. If you have non-roman characters then they may get lost, so a unicode table such as a table in a personal geodatabase is best. Text formats may be simple and easy to understand but a database table takes away the pain...food for thought.

Comment: I can't export into text file ... always giving me (.dbf). Also, I can't export the _Shape_Length_ field.

Comment: You are explicitly adding ".txt" to the end of the name? You could create another field and copy the length into if that geodatabase field does not export? Also I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: Yes I'm explicitly adding (.txt) to the end of the name. My version of ArcGIs is 10.2 so it might be a problem.

Comment: Have you looked at ArcScripts (now called code sharing), that should have been the first place you start looking. There are many user community created tools such as [this one](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431) which you can embed in your model.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! I used the _TableToCSV_ script. Worked quite like I wanted. I didn't know about that website so double thank you!

Comment: I am trying to export all of my geodatabase features' attribute table to .dbf.    through Copy rows and Table to Table. However, it seems that some of my columns are skipped. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a geoprocessing tool. Use toolbox "Conversion toools", go to "To Geodatabase", select the tool "[Table to Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-geodatabase.htm)". Select input, select output location (a directory). And the crucial part, write .txt in the output table name. It works.

Answer (score 1):

[Export Feature Attribute to ASCII](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/export-feature-attribute-to-ascii.htm) in the Spatial Statistics toolbox can also do such a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind trying arcpy, the following should generally work:

```
OutputFilePath = r"path\to\file"
with open(OutputFilePath, 'w') as outFile:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AttributeTableOrFeatureClass, "*") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for val in row:
                outFile.write("%s," % val)
        outFile.write("\n")
```