# Convert tabulate area's output format into a text file (.txt or .csv) in the ModelBuilder in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, tabulate

When I use the Tabulate Area tool, the original output's format is .dbf.

What can I do to export the output as a text file (.txt or .csv) in the ArcGIS ModelBuilder environment?

Comment: There is a tool for this, mentioned on GeoNet https://community.esri.com/thread/209993-attribute-table-to-csv which is in the spatial statistics toolbox Export Feature Attribute to ASCII http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p0000003v000000

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202750/exporting-attribute-table-to-text-file-txt-in-modelbuilder I hope it helps.